# How can I delete link of image that load data from other site?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this code in my html page for display weather data :

```
<!-- Begin ParsTOOLs.com Weather Code -->
<div  style="display:none;">
   <a href="http://iushop.ir">
      <h1>Weather</h1>
   </a>
</div>
<script language="javascript" src="http://www.ParstoolS.com/weather/code2/?city=IRXX0018&bgcolor=FFFFFF&textcolor=000000&width=180&height=300"></script>
<!-- End ‍Weather code -->
```

When I see the html page, this connect to **parstools.com** and load data from it. Data have an image that set one link to it.

How can I delete link of image(just display image without any link) with jquery ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `display: none;` in your css for that link to not be viewed.

Comment: It's that similar web service, I can't access the css data from it. Please test it and get me code.

Comment: oh, you might have no control over it if it's in an iframe. you can try getting the html and injecting it into your page, then using the solutions above to control those elements.